# Could not load type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver'

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

Using WebDriver for .NET4.0

I get a TypeLoadException when I run my program.

The message is:

```
Could not load type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver' from assembly 'WebDriver, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.":"OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver"
```

My code is a single line...

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\webdriver"); //chomedriver.exe is in this
```

directory.

Am using latest version 2.33.0.
Added reference to  webdriver and webdriver.support.

using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

[image: Properties of WebDriver Reference]

Also tried the non-client 4 framework target with no improvement.
[image: Project Properties]

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this problem today. My problem was that my project name was the same as the NuGet package I installed. I created a new project with a different name and the error went away.

Comment: I did the same error, my project name was "WebDriver". Had to create a new project with a different name and reinstall all packages to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I had seen a previous item where someone had the same trouble and solved it by closing and re-opening VS. I tried this and it did not fix my problem.

I did however open an entirely new project and started over. This time it worked. Very strange.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I tried to install Selenium with NuGet. The Selenium WebDriver package didn't include all the assemblies needed to run my browser test. Instead I went to the [Selenium download page](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) and downloaded the "Selenium Client & WebDriver" zip file for C#. I referenced all the dll files in that package and then my tests started working.

Maybe there are some other NuGet packages that can be used to get Selenium working, but I couldn't find them.

Answer (score 0):

I added this NuGet package DotNetSeleniumExtras.PageObjects.Core and it solved my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).