# C# - Could not load type FirefoxDriverService

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

I have the following code:

```
    FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(currentDir.Remove(0, 6), "geckodriver.exe");
    //service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
    service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox (x86)\firefox.exe";
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

But I get the following error:

> Error message: System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type
>   'OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverService' from assembly
>   'WebDriver, Version=2.45.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure the path you are using is the correct one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645008/could-not-load-type-openqa-selenium-chrome-chromedriver)

Comment: Yes 100%, it points to bin/debug and there "geckodriver" is found. Also firefox.exe is located in that path

Comment: Could be duplicated but I haven´t found a solution for my problem in that one.

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.45 is a pretty old WebDriver driver, it is from 2015. Above all, that assembly doesn't contain a type `FirefoxDriverService` so your code shouldn't have compiled in the first place.

What I expect, using my Crystall ball, is that you compiled against a newer version of the webdriver but in the copy step somehow a stale driver version made it into the folder you run your code from.

With the [current driver (3.4.0)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/3.4.0) and [version 0.16.1](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) of the Gecko driver your code example works for me, when I run it in LinqPAD

```
void Main()
{
    var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(
        ".",
        "geckodriver.exe");
    service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox (x86)\firefox.exe";
    var driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
}
```

Comment: Actually I´m using Selenium Webdriver version 3.4 and GeckoDriver 0.16.1 but I´m getting that error... I don´t know where to delete or remove that reference @rene

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. 
The thing was that Webdriver.dll was pointing to "PahntomJS.Xplatform.2.45.0.1" instead of "Selenium.WebDriver.3.4.0". The referense was bad.

What I did was removed Phantom from NuGet and reinstall Webdriver 3.4.0 and it worked!

In "project.csproj" it was displayed:

> Reference Include="WebDriver, Version=2.45.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL"
>
> ..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.PhantomJS.Xplatform.2.45.0.1\lib\net40\WebDriver.dll

And now it displays:

> Reference Include="WebDriver, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL"
>
> ..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.3.4.0\lib\net40\WebDriver.dll